# What was the first trigonometry book ever to appear containing most (or all) things we study nowadays in trigonometry

Tags: mathematics

What was the first Trigonometry book ever to appear containing most (if not all) things we study nowadays in Trigonometry?

I have heard that Pythagoras never wrote any book and that we have very few fragments of his writings. So which was the first book that contained most of the trigonometry as it is known nowadays?

Comment: It depends on what "most" and "as it is known nowadays" mean. Ancient trigonometry used chords instead of sines and cosines, Indians who introduced them did not write "as it is known nowadays" either, Euler wrote textbooks in something close to modern notation only in 18th century, but the substance was well-known by then. You better look at [History of trigonometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_trigonometry) and make the question more precise.

Comment: A good candidate is the book by Regiomontanus. (Johannes Muller). With one reservation: at that time people were more interested in spherical trigonometry than in the plane one, while nowadays it is not taught at all (except perhaps in some navigation schools).